# How to add views to a sql sync

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-view

Okay,

this is a knowledge question because googling for it is just frustrating. too many blogs have the word "view" on their pages (eg, views: 20000) but i'm searching for the sql server concept of a view, or rather, how to make sql sync recognize them. I tried adding them as a table but it insist they need primary keys. Any hints?

I Just need it to check to see if they exist, then create them on the localprovider from the remote. If anyone has any code that accomplishes this outside of sql sync that will be okay, too.

Comment: I answered this my self. You add it like you would a normal table with the  idea, like all things with sync, of a primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add it's name like you would normally, and make sure it has a primary key!
Treat it like a table.